# nVidia Optimus lookup

Tags: linux, gpu, process, optimus

How to know on which GPU a process run ? And how choose on which GPU a process will launch ? Because sometimes a process tells that my renderer is my APU but I want it to run on my GPU

OS: Linux

Distribution: Manjaro